# How to overlap columns using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a 3 columns composition:

col1 (span 3) - col2 (span 8) - col3 (span 3)

Col2 must be overlap by col1 and col3 in one column on each side, and they must be in the same row. What is the best way to create this composition using the twitter bootstrap responsive grid?

Comment: How do you mean "overlap"? That you cannot see the sides of col2 anymore? bs has a 12 column layout, so making spans that add up to 14 will not help

Comment: Yes, col1 and 3 must overlay col2. And that is the point, I need 14 columns to fit in a 12 grid. Am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You have three options:*

- **Use Twitter Bootstrap v1.XX where the grid was 16 instead of 12. Then you can do whatever you like with the two that will be left.**

Here the old docs with the latest v1.X (which is 1.4.0): http://bootstrapdocs.com/v1.4.0/docs/

As for the v1.4 bootstrap files, https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/v1.4.0

---

- **Customize your Bootstrap v2.XX build**

Here you customize everything and make a custom build: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Ps.:You will probably need to re-do all `span*` organization in yout HTML file if you use the customization option - that is, change to 14 (or 16) columns, as well as set new values for margin/padding.

*(Thanks @jmeas for pointing out the Customization, had forgotten that).*

---

- **Since you said they could've overlap, you could use the default build and use the following.**

What I did was get the `offset*` class and simply create a `offset-*`, with negative value.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">xx</div>
        <div class="span8 offset-1">yy</div>
        <div class="span3 offset-1">zz</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-fluid .offset-1 {
    margin-left: -10.638297872340425%;
    *margin-left: -10.53191489361702%;
}
.row-fluid .offset-1:first-child {
    margin-left: -8.51063829787234%;
    *margin-left: -8.404255319148938%;
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/CfEpr/)
I added some RGBA colors so you can see they overlap, while keeping the '12 grid'.

Comment: Not necessarily true; [Bootstrap is customizable](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html), including the number of columns and their widths. With that said, your creation of a new class for negative offsets is a good idea and how I'd go about this.

Comment: @jmeas Oh true, thanks for pointing the customization. Forgot it had that option. Will update the answer.

Comment: And, one more point: the margins in your answer only work with the default configuration of Bootstrap; the 12 column grid. If you plan to change the columns at all through the configuration page, you'll need to make changes to the .less files and compile those (unless you want to manually grab the offset values, which I wouldn't really recommend)