# How to overlap columns in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to create single row with two overlapping columns like that:

```
.row
  .col-sm-7
  .col-sm-6
```

so that 6th column of the grid is overlapped.

It's partially possible with a `.col-sm-pull-1`:

```
.row
  .col-sm-6
  .col-sm-6.col-sm-pull-1
```

but the 12th column becomes empty. I tried:

```
.row
  .col-sm-6
  .col-sm-7.col-sm-pull-1
```

but the second column moves to the next row.

I found the answer for Bootstrap 2 ([How to overlap columns using twitter bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654420/how-to-overlap-columns-using-twitter-bootstrap)). Is it possible with the Bootstrap 3?

Comment: Do you mean "overlapped" as in line break? Care to make a jsfiddle that recreates the problem?

Comment: I don't understand.  boostrap grid is 12 column only....why 7 + 6?

Comment: I'd like to achieve overlapping like this: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC554563.png

Comment: @scaisEdge I'd like 7 + 6 to fit in 12 by overlapping

Comment: Are you looking to have 13 columns in a 12 column layout with the middle of the 2 overlapped?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After seeing your image example, I think perhaps this is what you are looking for. (I made them overlap 2 columns because that will center it better)

```css
.blue{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);;
}
.row .red{
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
}
.red, .blue {
    height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="red col-xs-7"></div>
        <div class="blue col-xs-7 col-xs-push-5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcknmmy1/5/) If you want to overlap the two columns in one row, you'll need negative margins.  The bootstrap gutters/margins are layed out using positive and negative margins. I would recommend ids for the columns and then you can use z-index if you want one over the other one.
So change right margin on first and left margin on the second.

```
margin-right: -5%; 
margin-left: -5%;
```

[How the grid works](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) is a great reference for how its built.

Comment: This is a much better answer than using absolute position. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the new column under the same div as the one you want to overlap.

Here is an example

```
<style>
.first {
background-color: #dedef8;
border: solid black 1px;
}

.second {
 background-color: #dedef8;
 border: solid black 1px;
}
</style>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 first">
        <p>This is the first column</p>

     <div class="col-xs-6 second">
        <p>This is the second </p>   
     </div>
    </div>          
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Here's a jfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/NachoSupreme/o0fs78fv/

Comment: You are partially right. Inclusion is a form of overlapping but I'm looking for a solutions where columns are partially overlapped.

Comment: I think i found the answer to your problem in another thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121288/overlapping-rows-columns-using-bootstrap-grid check it out